# Play video and record from camera at the same time in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video

I'm working on a video diary app that plays a video (the video includes questions) NO AUDIO from the local library and also records the users responding to the video through the camera and microphone.

The video and recorder needs to start when the UI button is pressed and and when finished stop recording. So far following some tutorials I can play a video, when a button is pressed, from the local library using AVPlayerViewController and display a notification when the video has finished. However my attempts to use UIImagePickerController to activate the camera interfere with the playing of the video. Does anyone know of a tutorial or have some advice on how I could proceed?

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import MobileCoreServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var  playerController :  AVPlayerViewController!
    let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController! = UIImagePickerController()
    let saveFileName = "/test.mp4"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video", ofType: "mov")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:  path!)
        let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.didfinishPlaying(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player.currentItem)

        playerController.player = player
        playerController.player?.play()
//        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
//        imagePicker.cameraDevice = .Front
//        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
//        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
//        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
//        imagePicker.delegate = self
//          presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: {})

        self.presentViewController(playerController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    func didfinishPlaying(note : NSNotification){
        playerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Finished", message: "Video finished", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

Comment: Ask Ray! https://www.raywenderlich.com/94404/play-record-merge-videos-ios-swift